# How to use official Nix Docker image to test configuration?

Tags: nixos, nix

I'm trying to build [my Nix configuration](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root/-/merge_requests/70) in GitLab CI, to make sure any changes have at least a chance of working in NixOS. The [official Nix Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nixos/nix/) has a very different structure from NixOS (being [based on Alpine](https://github.com/NixOS/docker/blob/29925a65f96f8ed5c5ce63d70061504eb55299ac/Dockerfile#L3)), and I keep getting an error I've no idea how to resolve:

```
$ docker run --volume=$(pwd):/etc/nixos --interactive --rm --tty nixos/nix
5cc8dad8d887:/# nix-build /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
error: cannot auto-call a function that has an argument without a default value ('config')
```

Even the file generated by `nixos-generate-config` has the same problem:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ nixos-generate-config --root .
$ nix-build etc/nixos/configuration.nix
error: cannot auto-call a function that has an argument without a default value ('config')
```

The only other [repo](https://gitlab.com/kevincox/nix-ci/) I've found to do something similar is *much* more complex than what I was hoping to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Worked it out](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root/-/merge_requests/115/diffs), finally:

```
build:
  stage: test
  image: nixos/nix
  before_script:
  - echo system-features = kvm | tee -a /etc/nix/nix.conf
  - echo {} | tee common.nix hardware-configuration.nix host.nix
  - nix-env --install --attr nixpkgs.nixos-rebuild nixpkgs.man
  script:
  - nix-build '<nixpkgs/nixos>' -I nixos-config=ci.nix
  cache:
  - key:
      files:
      - configuration.nix
    paths:
    - /nix/store
```

ci.nix overrides some things to be able to build:

```
{ lib, ... }: {
  imports = [ ./configuration.nix ];
  boot = lib.mkForce { };
  environment.systemPackages = lib.mkForce [ ];
}
```

Caveat: To avoid running out of disk space (or having to create and maintain my own runners) I've emptied `environment.systemPackages` in ci.yml.